# Target odd elements throughout the document instead of just siblings

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the HTML code of the structure

```
<div>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
</div>
```

and I want the result where the `span` elements are coloured alternate red and black regardless of being siblings or not.

A fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/esjw5x9m/2/

If I use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`, the odd/even is selected on the position of that child with respect to its parent, whereas I am trying to select it on the basis of a global reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div:nth-child(odd) span:nth-child(odd){
  color: red;
}
div:nth-child(even) span:nth-child(even){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
  <span>abc</span>
</div>
```